# TypeError: Cannot read property 'readFileSync' of undefined NodeJS dom-parser

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, domparser

Trying to use Dom-Parser with Discord.js. Couldn't find help from any where else.
Error on line 15 `fs.readFile`
I also had a lot problems getting fs working. First it wasn't defined then it could not be runned before initalization, just got that fixed (I hope)

```
// Discord stuff.
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();
const config = require('./config.json');
const token = config.token;

// DomParser
var DomParser = require('dom-parser');
var parser = new DomParser();
var data = fs.readFileSync(filepathHidden);

// Other requirements
var fs = require('fs');


// when getting online. 
client.once('ready', () => {
    console.log('WAHAHAHA IM ALIVE!');
}),

fs.readFile('https://url.com)', 'utf8', function(err, html){
    if (!err){
      var dom = parser.parseFromString(html);
  
      console.log(dom.getElementsByClassName('new_solution_box_title').innerHTML);
    }
  })

client.login(token);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`var` is [hoisted](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Hoisting).

So since you have `var fs`, there is a variable called `fs` in the function / module / global scope where you have that statement.

It starts out undefined.

When you say `fs = require('fs')` you assign the file system module to it. At that point it stops being undefined.

On the **previous line** when you try to read it with `fs.readFileSync`, you **haven't yet defined it** so you get an error.

**Order matters**.

Answer (score 11):

See answer for same error in another stack overflow question.

The link to the answer that helped me is from [Arun Kumar Mohan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66214754/12991445)

What he recommended was to import as follows: `import * as fs from 'fs'`

Comment: This is what I had wrong, and solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

Please read NodeJS Documentation about [URL object support for FS API](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_url_object_support). It seems that only `file:` protocol is supported when using URLs.

However, I don't even recommend you to use `fs.readFileSync` because it is a blocking operation (code execution will stop until it finishes) and there is a network transfer involved.

Try fetching the file first instead using `fetch`, `XMLHttpRequest` or your preferred library, and then parse it. Or at least use `fs.readFile` which will perform its tasks asynchronously (`file:` protocol limitation still applies).

For the non defined error, you must import/require `fs` before using it. In other words, `var fs = require('fs')` must appear before any other use of `fs`.