# Nestjs readFileSync return Cannot read property 'readFileSync' of undefined

Tags: node.js, nestjs, readfile

I trying get file using method `readFileSync`:

```
import fs from 'fs';
import path from 'path';

const templateFile = fs.readFileSync(
    path.resolve(
    __dirname,
    '../mail/templates/exampleTemplate.html',
    ),
    'utf-8',
);
```

Nest still return me error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'readFileSync' of undefined

I tryied used to path: `./templates/exampleTemplate.html`, but result is the same

I have a structure file:

[image]

Comment: How are you requiring the `fs` module? Can you share the code with the `require` statement?

Comment: `import fs from 'fs';`

Comment: @ArunKumarMohan Your query is very helpful, I change `import` to `require`, and now get file work correctly. Thanks ;)

Comment: You're welcome. You can use `import` but it has to use a different syntax. I've explained in my answer.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Typescript does not have a default export of `fs`, which is could simply solved by aliasing the whole import.

```js
import * as fs from 'fs'
```

Comment: How is NextJS able to allow typescript files importing fs the normal way such as `import fs from 'fs'`?, is it through tsconfig.json?

Answer (score 13):

Try

```
import {readFileSync} from 'fs'
```

Answer (score 2):

I fix it by change:

```
import fs from 'fs';
import path from 'path';
```

to:

```
import fs = require('fs');
import path = require('path');
```